# Define a method for calculating the area of a figure in the Shape class

Tags: java

Define a base class that represents shapes: Shape. Define a method for calculating the area of a figure in the Shape class.

1. Create a circle class: Circle, Circle inherits the Shape class, and adds a new member attribute, which is a double-precision variable r representing the radius of the circle. Override the method of calculating the area of the parent class, which can calculate and return the area of a circle with a radius of r.
2. Create a rectangle class: Rectangle, Rectangle inherits the Shape class, and adds new member attributes, that is, two double-precision variables a and b representing the length and width of the rectangle. Override the method of calculating the area of the parent class, which can calculate and return the area of a rectangle whose length and width are a and b respectively.

---

```
package com.company;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        interface Shape {
            void calculateArea(double... a);
        }
        class Circle {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Shape shape = (double... a) ->
                        System.out.println("Area of circle is: " + Math.PI * a[0]);
                shape.calculateArea(1.55);
            }
        }
        class Rectangle {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Shape shape = (double... a) ->
                        System.out.println("Area of square is: " + a[0] * a[1]);
                shape.calculateArea(1.55, 2.55);
            }
        }
        public class Shapes {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: in last at public class shap{
}
it's showing red line under public
and after removing public when i run code it's shows no error but also doesn't show any result

Comment: Can you please give me the complete code for this question if it's possible for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 separate classes.
First

```
public abstract class Shape {
    abstract double calculateArea();
}
```

Second

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    private double r;

    @Override
    double calculateArea() {
        return Math.PI * r * r;
    }
}
```

And third

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
     private double a;
     private double b;

    @Override
    double calculateArea() {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Comment: @federico-klez-culloca Yes, you're right. But at least he wrote some code in his question, and provided not only a task. So I decided, that he tried to solve this issue himself, that's why I answered.